# What is the intuition for why all of math can be developed using set theory?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory

I learnt that the formal language of pure set theory allows one to formalize all mathematical notions and arguments. The language just has one non logical symbol(!) "the belongs to relation", this is *very* surprising to me, is there any intuition for why this is true? I mean its surprising that math has such a simple "building block".

Please note that I'm asking *why*(as in why is it intuitive) not *how* [I know how]

Comment: It is a remarkable success of 20th Century mathematics that set theory, with it seemingly conceptual simplicity, can represent most (all?) mathematical objects from any mathematical area, producing standard representations of simple mathematical objects such as numbers and functions as well as mathematical structures: groups, and so on, being de facto the most common “foundational framework".

Comment: I would not expect a student to accept this assertion unless they had already seen several examples of mathematical topics rigorously formulated in set theory language, such as group theory, the real numbers, vector space theory, topology, measure theory, ... It would even help if that student had learned ordinary precalculus and calculus with a set theoretic bent.

Comment: Well, it's hard to even justify this assertion to someone without a lot of background. I have no idea what your background is. But if I knew that you knew some group theory, and some topology, and some measure theory, then I might be able write up a justification.

Comment: @LeeMosher I know those why else will I learn set theory?

Comment: Okay, if you know these, it would be helpful to add such background information to your post. The few words of your post are insufficient for me to infer your mathematical background.

Comment: @LeeMosher Do you realise I am asking *why* not *how* ?

Comment: No, that is a subtle point that is not all evident from your post. I'm trying only to suggest ways in which you can improve your post, and invite better answers. To summarize my suggestions so far: explain your background; add some additional explanation to clarify what you are asking, e.g. to distinguish between *why* and *how*. These are all things that are generally expected of posts on this site, as you'll see by surfing through our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @LeeMosher I add an edit thanks for help.

Comment: *I know those why else will I learn set theory?* --- Many people learn (at least some) set theory without knowing anything about group theory and topology. I knew about countable and uncountable sets and basic cardinality results early in high school, long before I knew group theory or topology, and a fair amount of set theory is typically included in the "transition to advanced mathematics" type courses one takes before abstract algebra or real analysis or topology courses. Also, now-a-days with the internet and Wikipedia, this is probably more true.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I also don't know much about group theory I know analysis as much in Rudin frankly I'm not sure how this has got anything to do with the question. Also did you really learn *axiomatic* set theory in high school without knowing anything about analysis

Comment: No, I didn't learn axiomatic set theory at that time, but I had read in several places that set theory allows one to formalize all mathematical notions. As for what this has to do with your question, I was indicating why Lee Mosher was asking you to give some more context, such as your mathematical background.

Comment: Why the downvote? (Just curious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general most areas of math you can describe the objects of interest as ordered $n$-tuples where the first element of the tuple will be a set and the rest of the elements will be operations, relations, etc. For example a group is defined to be a pair $(G,*)$ where $*$ is an operation satisfying some axioms. Or $(X,d)$ is a said to be a metric space if $d: X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ satisfying symmetry, triangle equality, and point separability. The list goes on but since I can define most objects in mathematics in this way that means that one should be able to talk about most math just by being able to do the basic set operations (union, intersection, cartesian product, powerset ...) and have the basic numerical sets ($\mathbb{N}$,$\mathbb{Z}$,$\mathbb{Q}$,$\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{C}$). But all numerical sets can be defined using the basic set operations starting from $\mathbb{N}$. The definition of numerical sets from "simpler ones" was a project done way before the introduction of axiomatic set theory. We have that that in the early 19th century Hamilton formalizes the complex numbers starting from the reals. In the second half of the 19th century you see various attempts to formalized the set of real numbers. The two most famous constructions are the as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of the rationals that was done by Cantor and the second was as the set of Dedekind cuts. If you observe these constructions you notice you are using simple set theory operations to define them. Construction of the rationals from the integers is a case of a more general notion of the field of fractions of an integral domain which is itself a special case of localization. Finally the integers are built from the natural numbers through group completion. You can observe that all these constructions involve taking the cartesian product and defining equivalence classes.

One finally arrives to the natural numbers which can be defined as a class in $ZFC$ without infinity. The way these are defined are as the Von Neumann ordinals whose elements are either $0$ or a successor and are themselves either $0$ or a successor. One must assume the axiom of infinity to assure that the naturals exist as a set and thus one can apply set operations on them. Thus $ZFC$ or even $ZC$ is sufficient to do most of these constructions. Some of  more recent math such as the study of large cardinals or category theory often talk about objects that are a "too big".

Comment: Then for example, if we wanted to define a new function, it would just be part of a set of functions?

Comment: @TymaGaidash A new function from where to where? If you have a way of describing the function then you can simply use the axiom of separation on the cartesian product between the domain and the codomain. This is because you can state in first order logic that a subset of the cartesian product is a function. On the other hand if you want just any function you will have to use choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; Can you elaborate on "since I can define most objects in mathematics in this way that means that one should be able to talk about most math just by being able to do the basic set operations"

Comment: @Infinitesmal Once you have an object defined such as a group $(G,*)$ you have all the ingredients needed. For example you may ask if the operation is commutative. That will be defined by the sentece $\forall a,b \in G *(a,b)=*(b,a)$ so the property of commutativity is now a property on how a function $*:G\times G \rightarrow G$ behaves which in turn is a set property since you define functions to be subsets of the cartesian product or rather $*\subseteq (G\times G)\times G$ thus you can express commutativity solely in terms of sets.